# special permission to task in sequential workflow

Tags: workflow

I am using SpecialPermission in my Sequential Workflow createTask_MethodInvoking() function

`HybridDictionary taskPermissions = new HybridDictionary(); taskPermissions.Add(SPTaskProperties.AssignedTo, SPRoleType.Contributor); createTask1.SpecialPermissions = taskPermissions;`

which is working fine ..BUT when I edit the task and change the "Assigned TO" field to some other user then that task is not showing in that user task list(workflow task).

I am using following piece of code ,which is not working.

```
HybridDictionary taskPermissions = new HybridDictionary();
Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;
ht[SPBuiltInFieldId.AssignedTo] = SPTaskAfterProperties.AssignedTo;
taskPermissions.Add(SPTaskAfterProperties.AssignedTo, SPRoleType.Administrator);
createTask1.SpecialPermissions = taskPermissions;
createTask1.SpecialPermissions = taskPermissions; 
SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(task, ht, true);
```

suggest the way to reassign the task to other user with specialPermission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue I have fought with time and time again. The `SpecialPermissions` property of the `CreateTask` activity does not seem to update permissions on an already existing task.

In theory, you should be able to set up your `OnTaskChanged` event to detect a reassignment and permission the task item based on that. I've had iffy results doing it this way as well.

The solution I have settled on for all of my workflows has been to implement an `ItemUpdated` event receiver on the Tasks list that the workflow uses. In this event receiver, whenever the item is updated, you can check if the 'Assigned To' has changed, and re-permission appropriately.

Edit: Here's a snip of code that I use. In my case reassignments can be to a group or a specific user, so I handle both situations.

```
// Compare the new string value of the 'Assigned To' field on the task to the old value
// in the event afterproperties. If they differ, this task has been reassigned.
if (!GenericUtilities.StringValueFromField(listItem["Assigned To"]).Equals(properties.AfterProperties["AssignedTo"]))
{
    // Break role inheritance if not already done
    if (!listItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
    {
        // Reset inheritance first, to wipe out any other permissions
        listItem.ResetRoleInheritance();
        listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
    }

    // Determine if the assigned user is a group or user, and assign permissions as necessary
    SPFieldUserValue field = new SPFieldUserValue(listItem.Web, GenericUtilities.StringValueFromField(listItem["Assigned To"]));
    if (field.User != null)
    {
        SetItemLevelPermissions(listItem.Web, listItem, field.User);
    }
    else
    {
        SPGroup assignedGroup = listItem.Web.SiteGroups[field.LookupValue];
        SetItemLevelPermissions(listItem.Web, listItem, assignedGroup);
    }
}
```

The `SetItemLevelPermissions` method just takes the `SPPrincipal` that I pass and grants permissions on the task:

```
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = setSPWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
setListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

Comment: thanks for reply ... I think we both had the same problem so can you plz provide a piece of code that reassign task with permission. Because you have mentioned event receiver that solved your problem.

Comment: I think we both had the same problem so can you plz provide a piece of code that reassign task with permission. Because you have mentioned event receiver that solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I updated the answer with some code.